# Windows 8 App Slow Performance with ListView

Tags: performance, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am building a Windows 8 app and I thought I would test it on my wife's tablet - Asus Vivo Smart Tab - and I noticed it runs a little choppy when switching screens, every other aspect of the app runs fine. After a little more testing I noticed that one page didn't load slowly - it was the only page without a WinJS.UI.ListView control. So I did some testing. I commented out all code (except necessary code) on a different page of my app, one WITH a ListView. I even removed graphics and got it down to the basic boiler plate code, except I left these lines in:

```
<div id="publisherListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>
```

The page still loaded slowly on my wifes tablet. Then I commented the above code out and Bada-Bing, it ran smoothly!! Now I know the Asus tablet is not the fastest on the market, but it runs many other apps smoothly through page transitions and they all have ListViews. What is going on here? Do I have an old version of WinJS? Here's what I'm using:

```
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the itemDataSource or itemTemplate of this ListView being set anywhere in JavaScript or is it just an empty control on an empty page?

Comment: Empty page, and no datasource, templates, or other attributes are being set.

Comment: @skinneejoe try replacing the ListView with a FlipView and see whether you're still experiencing the choppiness.